# How do I open a file in vim MRU with vertical split

Tags: vim

How do I open a file in vim MRU with vertical split

`:MRU` gives me list.

How do I open the file in split window?

I tried docs. But I don't find any info. Might be I am missing it

Comment: do you know which plugin defined the `:MRU` command? it is not standard vim feature. Do NOT use any "vim-distribution", if it was the case.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521, Following MRU I am using. It has other commands but not vertical split.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MRU list itself will always appear at the bottom of the tab page. To open the selected file in a vertical split, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. This has been added in MRU version 3.4:

> Added new mapping for opening files in a vertically split window from the MRU widow (key O).

Comment: This is working. But not like as I expected. It is pushing my existing vertical layouts to horizontal and then it is creating a vertical split.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. If I already had 3 vertically split windows, it creates a fourth for me. Do you have any other window-management plugins? If you can isolate this to MRU, please report the problem to its author.